# Python Pandas GroupBy: calculating age by subtracting date from the last 10 years

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe which looks like below:

df:

```
   ID             DATE  
     KV          26/09/1969 0:00:00         
     KV          27/05/1970 0:00:00         
     KV          17/01/1989 0:00:00        
     KV          27/05/1970 0:00:00        
     DV          24/07/1984 0:00:00         
     DV          11/03/2015 0:00:00        
     DV           4/12/2015 0:00:00         
     GV          26/10/2005 0:00:00         
     GV          11/10/2017 0:00:00         
     GV          11/10/2017 0:00:00
```

Now I want to create an average age column for each ID for the last 10 years (using groupby).

Desired Output:

```
Average Age
ID  2020    2019    2018    2017    2016    2015    2014    2013    2012    2011
KV  45.5    44.5    43.5    42.5    41.5    40.5    39.5    38.5    37.5    36.5
DV  15.3    14.3    13.3    12.3    11.3    31       30      29      28      27
GV  3        2       1       0      0        0      0         0       0       0
```

Age can be calculated by the last 10 years subtracting from the date column. I used the following command to calculate the age for the year 2020:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Date'].agg(lambda x:pd.datetime('01-04-2020')-x['Date'])
```

However, I am not able to figure out how to calculate the age value for last 10 years with a single command. Could anyone help me how to approach this issue?

Comment: Why's DV's age decreasing between 2015-16? is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a year column like `df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year` and then do a `groupby` on both `['ID','Year']` like:

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_date(td):
    ### no leap-year in account
    resYear = float(td.days)/365.0                   
    resMonth = int((resYear - int(resYear))*365/30) 
    resYear = int(resYear)
    return str(resYear) + "Y" + str(resMonth) + "m"

df = pd.DataFrame([['KV','26/09/1969 0:00:00'],['KV','26/09/1979 0:00:00'],['KV','26/09/1989 0:00:00'],['DV','26/09/1984 0:00:00'],['GV','26/09/2014 0:00:00']],columns=['id','date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['age'] = df.groupby(['id','year'])['date'].apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime('today')-x).reset_index()['date'].apply(parse_date)
df
```

output:

[image]

Once that's done `pd.pivot_table` should allow you to put years into columns.

Comment: Problem how to calculate age of ID in last 10 years. The way you mentioned does not calculate the age. It only generates the year column, not the age column

Comment: can you paste your actual data? I can play with it and post the actual code.

But, it seemed you already have the code for calculating age?

Comment: ID             DATE  
     KV          26/09/1969 0:00:00         
     KV          27/05/1970 0:00:00         
     KV          17/01/1989 0:00:00        
     KV          27/05/1970 0:00:00        
     DV          24/07/1984 0:00:00         
     DV          11/03/2015 0:00:00        
     DV           4/12/2015 0:00:00         
     GV          26/10/2005 0:00:00         
     GV          11/10/2017 0:00:00         
     GV          11/10/2017 0:00:00

Comment: Thanks for that. When you calculate the age, you subtract the date from today which is correct for calculating for Year 2020. If you read my post again, I also want to calculate for last 10 years (i.e. 2020,2019, 2018, 2017, 2016,2015,2014,2013,2012,2011)